# AC/DC - Current generator with short circuit

Tags: ac, dc, current-source, short-circuit

I have the following circuit (AC regime):

[image]

I am given the current **I** in the branch **4-5**. I don't understand what happens with **Ig2** here. Is it annulled? Should the circuit look like this:

[image]

What would be if, instead of current generator **Ig2**, we had voltage generator, **E1** for example? Would it be annulled?

Comment: Could you remove Ig2 if the circuit only comprised Ig2 and the short circuit 4-5?

Comment: @Chu, No, but that would be different scenario than this . It would be closed circuit that contains only Ig2, and not I.

Comment: @Chu, Is it Ig2=I in this case?

Comment: Well, Ig2=-I would be correct, given the directions of the current arrows. Remember, a 'perfect' length of wire does not need a voltage across it in order for it to carry a current.

Comment: @Chu, When we have done that (Ig2=-I), can we annulle Ig2 just like the second picture in the original post?

Comment: ... because current in the branch 1-5 is equal to zero?

Comment: The point is that you cannot remove a current generator simply because it has a short circuit across it.

Comment: @Chu, What if instead of Ig2, we had voltage generator E1, for example? Would it be annulled?

Comment: Why is the current in 1-5 zero? You are making arbitrary decisions. Just solve the circuit as it stands.

Comment: One question per post is the rule. changing Ig to a voltage generator is a completely different problem.

Comment: @Chu, Current in the branch 1-5 is zero by the Kirchhoff's circuit current law if you apply it on node 5. I+Ig2=I15

Comment: I+Ig2=0 only if all the other components disappear - read my comment carefully. We're going round in circles now.

Comment: @Chu, Ok, I understand that. But what if, instead of Ig2, we had E1, for example?

Comment: Are you reading my comments? Different circuit = new question.

Answer (score 2):

The current of Ig2 must flow through the short circuit between node 4 and 5. It has no other influence on the rest of the circuit.

To see why, just apply superimposition, leaving only Ig2 active. You'll have Ig2 with its terminal shorted, so no voltage across them. Anything else connected between node 4 and 5 cannot be powered, since it is passive and its terminals are connected to a "0V source".

You can actually remove Ig2 from your circuit, but you must add its value to I, because in the first circuit the value of I comprises some component due to the rest of the circuit (let's call it Ix) minus Ig2. The remaining part of the circuit will work the same.

The equation will be:

I = Ix - Ig2 => Ix = I + Ig2

where I assume Ix has the same direction as I. In other words, Ix is your I in the second circuit.

Comment: You said at the end that Ix has the same direction as I. But that can't be possible by your equation. Could you explain if I am wrong?

Comment: The direction of current and voltages shown in a circuit are arbitrary references. The direction of I is clearly shown in the schematic. My equation assumes Ix is chosen with the same direction, otherwise a minus sign in front of Ix should be placed. Once you choose the direction of Ix, the equation is an application of superimposition theorem.

Answer (score -2):

It looks to me that the current from IG2 can go two ways, against I(branch 4-5) producing what flows in there and also thru resistor Z1.
Removing IG2 will affect the circuit and will change both the I(branch 4-5) and the current thru Z1. Additionally, all other components will be affected.

So the current from IG2 goes against the I(branch 4-5) and removing IG2 will thus increase the I(branch 4-5).

Comment: This is incorrect. All of the current from Ig2 must flow through the short, as Lorenzo explains. No other components will be affected.